# What is the best practice to use data structures/containers for different types in C?

Tags: c, types, coding-style

Since C doesn't have templates or generics, do I have to write one specific copy for one type? And what is the suggested naming for the structures? Are there any recommended standards on this?

Comment: No, typically containers in C store (properly aligned) blobs of data, which correspond to a specific type.  For example, you might have something like `List_init(&my_list, sizeof(int));` which will initialize `my_list` to be a list of  blobs of size `sizeof(int)`.  Then the list can provide a `void *` to a stored blob that the List user can cast to their specific type (e.g. - `int *`).  That's the most common way generic containers are implemented in C.  More advanced versions can implement template like functionality using macros, but I'd recommend mastering the blob way first.

Comment: If you need this for actual usage though, and not just to train yourself how to code such things in C, then you probably want to use a popular library that already implements such things instead.  Maybe glib? https://developer.gnome.org/glib/